# My caching system causes a memory leak

Tags: ios, swift, caching, memory-leaks

I have a data structure that I have created that caches items using a combination of a Dictionary and a Queue. The idea is that items are added to the "Cache" and once it reaches its limit, the oldest item in the cache is removed:

```
struct Cache<A: Hashable, B> {
    fileprivate var theCache = [A:B]()
    fileprivate var keyQueue = Queue<A>()
    fileprivate var maxItems: Int!

    init(maxItems: Int) {
        self.maxItems = maxItems
    }

    subscript(key : A?) -> B? {
        get {
            if key != nil {
                return theCache[key!]
            }
            return nil
        }
        set(newValue) {
            // If value being added to cache, check that the max no. of items isn't exceeded.
            // If it is then remove the first item of the cache queue and add value to queue.
            if key != nil {
                if (theCache.count + 1 > maxItems) {
                    removeFirstItem()
                }
                addValue(key!, value: newValue)
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     Tells us how many items there are in the cache

     - returns: The count of the cache
     */
    var count: Int {
        return theCache.count
    }

    mutating func clear() {
        theCache.removeAll()
        for _ in 0..<keyQueue.count {
            _ = keyQueue.dequeue()
        }
    }

    fileprivate mutating func addValue(_ key: A, value: B?) {
        theCache[key] = value // Memory leak 2
        keyQueue.enqueue(key)
    }

    fileprivate mutating func removeFirstItem() {
        let firstItemKey = keyQueue.dequeue()
        if firstItemKey != nil {
            theCache.removeValue(forKey: firstItemKey!)
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using this to cache `UIImages` in a `UICollectionView`, and have a strong reference to this cache from my `model` class.

Inside my `cellForItemAt` method, I have the following code to check for cached images. If there is a cached image then it adds that to the `UICollectionCell` otherwise it downloads it, adds it to the cache, then adds it to the `UICollectionCell`:

```
if let cellImage = model.imageCache[urlString] {
    cell.imageView.image = cellImage
}
else {
    model.downloadImage(
        urlString,
        completion: { [weak self] (error, image) -> () in
            if let strongSelf = self {
                if error == nil {
                    // Store the image in to our cache
                    strongSelf.model.imageCache[urlString] = image
                    // Update the cell with our image
                   if let cellToUpdate = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? MyCollectionCell {
                        cellToUpdate.imageView.image = image
                    }
                }
                else {
                    print("Error downloading image: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                }
            }
        }
    )
}
```

However, according to Xcode 8 this whole process is causing a memory leak for the UIImages. Can anyone help me out with where the memory leak is occurring and how I can prevent it?

**EDIT**

Here's my `downloadImage` function. I've also added "Memory leak 1" and "Memory leak 2" as comments next to my code to show the backtrace of the memory leak xcode shows me:

```
Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .get)
         .authenticate(usingCredential: credentials!)
         .validate()
         .downloadProgress { bytesRead, totalBytesRead, totalBytesExpectedToBeRead  in
             DispatchQueue.main.async {
                 progress?(Float(totalBytesRead)/Float(totalBytesExpectedToBeRead))
             }
         }
         .responseData { response in
             // Convert the downloaded data in to a UIImage object
             var image: UIImage?
             if response.result.error == nil {
                 image = UIImage(data: response.data!) // Memory leak 1
             }
             completion(response.result.error, image)
         }
```

Comment: You add images continuously, but you never remove any.  Figure out a least recently used and max cache size strategy..

Comment: @duffymo the line `if (theCache.count + 1 > maxItems) { removeFirstItem() }` does that.

Comment: If that's the case, why are you concerned?  Where is the memory leak coming from?  Have you profiled and measured the runtime behavior under a realistic load condition?

Comment: @duffymo I'm going through Xcode 8's new memory profiler and it's telling me 8 `UIImage`s have leaked (which are all the ones on screen). I've updated my question to show where the leaks are coming from according to Xcode. Under realistic conditions it seems to be fine, but if it says there's a leak I should probably look into it right?

Comment: Leak means the memory you allocated can't be reclaimed. Your code removes a reference from a data structure. Should you perform a remove for the image memory before you remove the reference?

Comment: @duffymo By removing all the references to the image, ARC should deallocate the memory. I can't see any other way to "perform a remove for the image memory"?

Comment: "Should" is the key word. That's not true of objects like file handles and database connections in Java. Don't assume.  Believe the profiler.